# custom UIView animation in dismissModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, catransition

Where is the correct place to put custom animation code for dismissing a modalviewcontroller.

I tried putting the following into viewdiddisappear, viewwilldisappear but doesn't behave correctly.  Any thoughts? THanks!!

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"suck" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPointMake(260, 431)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the **outgoing** `UIViewController`? I don't think you can affect that. What is the desired effect?

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.  I am trying to dismiss a modal view into like a trash can (similar to the Photos app and Mail app effect).  The problem is when I do this animation, it creates a layer on top of the modal view and performs the animation on that layer.  But after the effect, the modal view still appears.

Comment: Then do the animation and, in a completion block, call 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO'. That will get rid of the 'UIViewController' more or less immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  I followed the example in:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BubbleLevel/Introduction/Intro.html

Basically removed the second view from superview and inserted the first view back in.  The transition works correctly afterwords.

THanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UIViewController *myController = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewAnimationTransition transition = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp; // or whatever effect you want
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:[self window] cache:YES];
[navController presentModalViewController:myController animated:NO]; // or dismissModalViewController in your case
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately dismissing it right away gets rid of the animation on the screen.